# Why sbt is trying to get a specific version of itself

Tags: sbt

I have sbt 0.13.8 installed.

However when type sbt in a folder, sbt is trying to get version 0.13.6 of itself. And I didn't find anything in the build.sbt file that could explain the strange behavior. Please tell me why.

Here is the contents of the build.sbt file.

```
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)

name := "quiz-management-service"

version := "0.1"

organization := "com.danielasfregola"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers ++= Seq("Typesafe Repository" at    "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
              "Spray Repository"    at "http://repo.spray.io")

libraryDependencies ++= {
val akkaVersion       = "2.4.4"
val sprayVersion      = "1.3.3"
Seq(
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"      % akkaVersion,
"io.spray"          %% "spray-can"       % sprayVersion,
"io.spray"          %% "spray-routing"   % sprayVersion,
"io.spray"          %% "spray-json"      % "1.3.3",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j"      % akkaVersion,
"ch.qos.logback"    %  "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit"    % akkaVersion  % "test",
"io.spray"          %% "spray-testkit"   % sprayVersion % "test",
"org.specs2"        %% "specs2"          % "2.3.13"     % "test"
)
}

// Assembly settings
mainClass in Global := Some("com.danielasfregola.quiz.management.Main")

jarName in assembly := "quiz-management-server.jar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. sbt version can be forced in the build.properties under the project folder, using the syntax sbt.version=0.13.x